# Logbback xml - Conditionally add MDC Variables if they exist?

Tags: logback, logback-classic

I have configured my logback to look like this:

```
<pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [env=${environment}] [app=${app.name}] [version=${version.version}] [level=%level] [thread=%thread] [logger=%logger] [X-REQUEST-ID=%mdc{X-REQUEST-ID:--}] %msg %n</pattern>
```

What this does is that if it doesn't find `X-REQUEST-ID` in context then it logs like this:

Currently:
`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS [env=dev] [app=sample] [version=2] [level=INFO] [thread=...] [logger=...] [X-REQUEST-ID=-]`

however, I want to eliminate the complete statement: `[X-REQUEST-ID=-]`

Expected:

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS [env=dev] [app=sample] [version=2] [level=INFO] [thread=...] [logger=...]` (Nothing at all for X-RE

and let other parameters be printed if X-REQUEST-ID doesn't get detected in MDC context.

Can someone help me rewrite the pattern block in that case?